# UWP Access violation exception when activating any input field

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

Something strange happens with my app.

Windows 10 UWP Application, works fine on PC and on some phones. But on my lumia 730 (with latest preview build) and on devices of some my customers app crashes when you trying to activate any input field.

`Application "[7376] <AppName>.exe" has terminated with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.`

Theres no any stacktrace and other error messages. How I can debug the error and find the trouble?

UPD: Windows certification kit says that everything is allright

UPD2: In emulator of Windows 10 build 14393 I ahve the same trouble

UPD3: I did turn on machine code debugging and load the pdb files.
Now I have an error in wrl\client.h on these lines:

```
// query for U interface
    template<typename U>
    HRESULT As(_Inout_ Details::ComPtrRef<ComPtr<U>> p) const throw()
    {
        return ptr_->QueryInterface(__uuidof(U), p);
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: *"In emulator of Windows 10 build 14393 I ahve the same trouble"* - With the emulator, you can attach a debugger, though, and break, when the exception is **thrown**, which takes you right where the problem starts.

Comment: @IInspectable debugger was active. I have no any idea what to do (

Comment: In that case, we cannot help you. Consult your debugger's manual, and provide the required information, once you know how to use it.

Comment: Can an access violation even be caught though? It seems irrevocable.